# How to add days to whole entire date object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add 7 days to the entire date object, but it does not work. I keep getting the same date plus the number I am trying to add at the end.

```
   var d = new Date();
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
      dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + i);
      console.log(dat);
    }
```

Comment: The `+` in your expression will convert both arguments to string, so it is a string concatenation you are doing.

Comment: I don't want to do getDate or getDay, instead I need to grab the whole entire date object

Comment: Try `d.addDays(i)`

Comment: addDays would be undefined, if you are referring to the link marked as duplicate, that will not work because that returns the just the day I need the whole date object

Comment: var newDates = d + 86400 * i

Comment: Still does string concatenation

Comment: The referred to answer returns a date object ("an entire date object").

Comment: I updated my code, but I get the error `Invalid Date
`

Comment: Your questions is quite unclear. What is `this` in `this.valueOf()`? What's the point of declaring `d = new Date()`? Why is there a loop? Why can't you do `var dat = new Date(); dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + 7); console.log(dat);`, as indicated in the duplicate?